# how do i disable only a few selected mouse events

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, pointer-events

I am trying to disable only a few selected mouse events on a div.

my end goal here is to create a div that I can drag a single image to and from it (which I easily done), but when the div is empty it enables me to drag whatever is placed underneath of it.

I tried to use CSS- Pointer-events: none; but it disables all events, so I can't even drag to it.

I have also tried to play around with the z-index property, but that didn't work out either. (I need the div to have a higher z-index)

I am using HTML 5 for my drag and drop, and I would like to keep it that way, and not use Jquery or other solutions that are out there.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault() method to disable event.

> **Description:** If this method is called, the default action of the event
>   will not be triggered.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: it doesn't disable the event, it stops the default action. for ex. a link wont direct to the page linked, but it will still run the entire function attached. I want to disable it altogether, so it will have the same effect as pointer-events: none;